# Android Studio cambiar color de letra spinner dependiendo del caso

Tags: android, spinner, color, studio

tengo una consulta en Android Studio un spinner se le puede cambiar el color de letra dependiendo de lo que yo quiera por ejemplo:

Si el número es 1 que salga la letra de color roja
Si el número es 2 que salga la letra de color azul
Si el número es 3 que salga la letra de color verde

Y así hasta llenar todo el spinner

Pregunto porque he estado buscando información pero solo he encontrado de cambiar todo en un solo color, gracias de ante mano, saludos!!!

´´´
public void CargarPisos(String codigosector) {

```
    final Spinner cmbPisos = findViewById(R.id.cmb_Piso);
    int datosConsultadoCODIGO = 0;
    String datosConsultadoNOMBRE= "";
    int pos=0;
    try {
        //Se obtiene la conexión

        Connection connect = gen.conexionBD();
        //Se genera la consulta
        Vpisos= new int[50000];
        Vtipoespacio= new int[50000];
        VTamNormal=new String[50000];
        Statement st = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT E.cod_espacio AS CODIGO,E.cod_tipo_espacio as TIPOESPACIO,E.tam_espacio as TAMANOESPACIO, (E.cod_espacio_pima + ' / '+ CASE E.ind_estado WHEN 'O' then 'Ocupado' when 'L' then 'Libre' when 'T' then 'Tramite' when 'R' then 'No Dispo' when 'E' then 'Ocu plaza' else 'No encontrado' end) AS NOMBRE FROM cen_espacios AS E WHERE E.cod_sector=" +(codigosector)+ " ORDER BY E.ind_estado asc,NOMBRE");
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Se extraen los datos
            datosConsultadoCODIGO = rs.getInt("CODIGO");
            datosConsultadoNOMBRE = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
            Vpisos[pos]= rs.getInt("CODIGO");
            Vtipoespacio[pos]= rs.getInt("TIPOESPACIO");
            VTamNormal[pos]= rs.getString("TAMANOESPACIO");
            lstPisos.add(new ModeloPisos(datosConsultadoCODIGO,datosConsultadoNOMBRE));
            pos=pos+1;
        }


        ArrayAdapter<ModeloPisos> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ModeloPisos>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lstPisos);

        cmbPisos.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Se cierra la conexión
        connect.close();
        //Mostramos los datos obtenidos


    } catch (SQLException e) {
```

mensaje.MostrarMensjae(this,"Error al cargar los pisos");

```
    }

} '''
```

Ahí lo que deseo es que cada vez que agrego algo al **lstPisos** dependiendo de lo que sea que **tenga un color de letra** para después agregarlo al **adapter** y al **spinner**

Comment: Si entiendes el codigo aqui tienes una solucion https://wlzhong.wordpress.com/2016/11/03/android-spinner-%E7%9A%84%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E4%BB%A5%E5%8F%8A%E9%80%B2%E9%9A%8E%E7%94%A8%E6%B3%95/

Comment: Si se puede realizar, agrega el código de lo que estas realizando.

Comment: Listo ya agregue el código, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo extender de ArrayAdapter para que puedas definir el criterio con el que vas a asignar los colores

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModeloPisos> {
    private List<ModeloPisos> items;
    
    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<ModeloPisos> items) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ModeloPisos getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView=new TextView(getContext());
        //Asignas el texto que quieres mostrar
        textView.setText(items.get(position).toString());//o la propiedad de Modelo Pisos que quieras mostrar
        //Obtienes los colores que quieras usar
        int color=getContext().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        //Defines tu criterio para asignar colores
        switch (items.get(position).toString()){
            case "Un criterio": textView.setTextColor(color);
            break;
        }
        return textView;
    }
}
```

Y luego lo usas así

```
 MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lstPisos);
 cmbPisos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias me funciono correctamente!!! De verdad muchas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: Ayudanos marcando la respuesta de @danms07 como solucion,